# Read image from folder using php or database

Tags: php, mysql, database, file

Is it better to read and list images directly from file system using simple php, or is it better to store image meta info and filename in the database and access the images by doing a mysql select. What are the pros and cons of both solutions.

Comment: Needs more info. What are you doing? On what scale?

Comment: @pekka Users will be uploading images, image gets stored under a folder named after the login id of the user. Then users can later login to access all there uploaded images.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading from MySQL is faster or reading from a file is faster??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138197/reading-from-mysql-is-faster-or-reading-from-a-file-is-faster)

Comment: @Johan this is not a duplicate, i'm not asking if i should store the images in the database. Please read the question.

Comment: @pinkie that post isnt suggesting you store the images in the db. Its merely asking if its faster to read from a file vs from the db

Comment: @Aschere, i read the psot, it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Listing files on a file system** is probably the easiest way to accomplish what you trying to do but it's going to be *very* slow if you are trying to cycle through several thousand directories/files on a networked file system (NFS, CIFS, GlusterFS, etc).

**Storing files in a database** will create a much more overhead since you are now involving an external application to store information. You have to remember that every time you are using a database you are also using network I/O, authentication mechanism, query parser, etc. At the same time all of this overhead might provide for a faster response then using a networked file system.

To conclude - everything depends on amount of files you are working with and underlying infrastructure. Two major things to look out for are going to be disk I/O and network I/O.

Comment: He's **not** trying to store the image files in the Database; he's wondering whether he should read file metadata out of the filesystem as he traverses it, or whether it's better to store that metadata in a database.

Comment: I was referring to listing files in a directory and not storing files themselves in the database. Simply running "ls" command on a directory with anything over 500 files on a remote server (NFS, GlusterFS, whatever) can take a loooong time.

Comment: So you are saying storing filepath in the database makes it faster to read images in the folder. Let's say we have 500 users each accessing his own folder that contains 100 image each.

Comment: Again, everything depends on underlying infrastructure, amount of files, and application concept.

Also, there is going to be a major difference in what type of file system is used and what type of database is used. In fact, it will be much faster to query a Redis database then to list 5,000 files on an ext4 file system. On the other hand, listing 5,000 files from ReiserFS will be faster then doing so from MySQL InnoDB database.

Comment: Also, it would be much more beneficial to store **file metadata** (mime type, file size, creation timestamp, etc) in the database then to read it from file system every time. Now, database doesn't have to be relational - it can be a simple key/value store like Memcache or even PHP's APC. There is simply too much overhead of reading file information from file system every time.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Upload all the images in one directory
2. Store references to those images that are tied to the uploader's User ID
3. Then just select the image URLs that are tied to that ID, and output them however necessary.

Comment: No really looking to secure the images. All that needs to be done with the images, is reading them. If we have a allot of images in the folder, i was just wondering if it would be faster to read them directly from the folder or if i should store the image filename in the database then them ready the image using a select statement which would match the filename in the database to the image in the folder.

Comment: are u suggesting to store the images in the database?

Comment: Nope. Just shove them all in one folder (with a unique ID in the filename to prevent duplicates overwriting each other) and then store those paths in the Database for reference.

Comment: For the most case, all images will be read from the folder at once. Why is storing filepath in the database then point it to the images in the folder faster , Why not just read the images directly from the folder. That was my question

Comment: Oh.. If you're going to be reading the entire list, then doing it directly from the filesystem is **definitely** going to be faster! If you're traversing the directories looking for single files, however, then a database will be a much better solution.

Comment: @pinkie how many images are we talking about, and in what kind of application? @BraedenP hit the nail on the head

Comment: @ascherer, i'm reading otherwise where database is faster then reading from folder.  Let's say we have 500 users each accessing his own folder that contains 100 image each

Comment: @pinkie if you are grabbing all the images from a single users directory, using the file-system route would be faster

Comment: Even think about it in logical terms, Pinkie: If you read them directly from the filesystem, you read the metadata and do whatever you're doing with the image. If you use the database, you connect to the DB server, select the properties of all 500 images, and then go to the filesystem anyway and load all the images. It just makes sense that the direct filesystem approach would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

People find it easier to store their files within folders and parse that folder with php. If you go the database method the database eventually gets larger and larger and larger.

I can see it becoming personal preference, but I personally have gone with parsing folders for images rather than storing it within a database.

Depends on the scale of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would be doing.

1. Store the file metadata in the database. You can store quite a bit of information about this image this way.
2. Store the image file on a distributed storage system like Amazon S3. Store the path in your metadata. Replication is part of the system. And it easily integrates with Cloudfront CDN.
3. Distribute the the images through Amazon Cloudfront CDN.